# Remove Click Events From All Elements

Tags: jquery

I'm aware of .on() and .off(), but how can I do something to ALL elements on the entire page?  Something like this:

```
$('all-elements').off('click');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [*(all element)](http://api.jquery.com/all-selector/) selector

```
$('*').off('click');
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you!  I'll accept your answer in 13 minutes.  I can't upvote.

Comment: Note that this removes only those event handlers that were added with jQuery in the first place, not handlers added with plain JS or other libraries. (Which may be all that you need, but I thought it worth pointing out.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  That's -exactly- what I want actually so it works, but it's great to know for the future.  Does it only work with handlers added with .on(), or others as well, such as those added with .click()?

Comment: @user3011922 it removes all the handlers added by jQuery because method like `click`()` calls `.on()` internally